# Python: OverflowError: math range error

Tags: python, math, overflow

I get a Overflow error when i try this calculation, but i cant figure out why.

```
1-math.exp(-4*1000000*-0.0641515994108)
```

Comment: It's taking forever to calculate the math.exp of your expression in linux `calc` - actually around 3 minutes on my PC. The output didn't fit on screen, but here's the last part of it: 72601064848030549330052235283692208900018564830019400961030549300613573049038658490326003709885716700599883485335384987825755170505520081515667880006364976728119694600659746416440802282624919298297947165561974790549306225384099033699937030324423057761382164874383992786304290520859618809208146480637711575173287535774531529104427355177803053295844887694582338200906830029698966101673406039727344889895537434766431106

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The number you're asking math.exp to calculate has, in decimal, over 110,000 digits.  That's slightly outside of the range of a double, so it causes an overflow.

Answer (score 29):

To fix it use:

```
try:
    ans = math.exp(200000)
except OverflowError:
    ans = float('inf')
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the value gets too large to fit into a `double` in python which is why you get the `OverflowError`. The largest value I can compute the `exp` of on my machine in Python is just sligthly larger than 709.78271.

Answer (score 5):

Try np.exp() instead of math.exp()

> Numpy handles overflows more gracefully, np.exp(999) results in inf
>   and 1. / (1. + np.exp(999)) therefore simply results in zero

```
import math 
import numpy as np

print(1-np.exp(-4*1000000*-0.0641515994108))
```

Answer (score 4):

This may give you a clue why:

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=math.exp%28-4*1000000*-0.0641515994108%29
```

*Notice the 111442 exponent.*

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no one explained what the real solution was. I solved the problem using:

from mpmath import *

You can find the documentation below:

http://mpmath.org/

Comment: Here you can find the expo() method https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/powers.html#exponentiation