# newton fractal: mathoverflow error

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have written a python code for a newton method in 1D and want to use it to calculate the newton fractal for the function [image: f(x)]

The basic python code I am using is this:

```
error = 1e-10
resolution = 100

x_range = np.linspace(-2,2,resolution)
y_range = np.linspace(-1,1,resolution)

fraktal = np.zeros(shape=(resolution,resolution))


for i in range(resolution):
    for j in range(resolution):
        x = x_range[i]
        y = y_range[j]
        z = complex(x,y)
        fraktal[i,j] = newton(z,error)

plt.imshow(fraktal)
plt.show()
```

My newton()-function returns the number of iterations it needed to find an approximation xk such that |f(xk)|<1e-10.

I tested this code with [image: f(x)] and it worked, but when I use the actual function I would like to use, namely [image: f(x)], I get an Overflow Error, "OverflowError: math range error".
This is my code for the function f:

```
import cmath as cm

def f(x):
    y = pow(x,4)*cm.cos(x) - 1
    return y
```

I don't really know how to debug this. I tried to convert to double precision, but my web research suggested that python is already using double precision. That's about the only idea I have for solving this.

Does anyone have an idea for what to do here? Thanks!

Edit:

```
def grad(x):
    h = 1e-6
    y = (f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2*h)
    return y

def newton(x0,error):
    k = 1

    xk = x0

    while 1:
        xk = xk - f(xk)/grad(xk)

        err = abs(f(xk))

        if err < error:
            return k
            break
        if k > 100:
            return 100
            break

        k = k+1
```

Comment: No LaTex here my friend. Using [CodeCogs](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) would be nice on the eyes though.

Comment: how about sharing the `newton` function code as well?

Comment: okay I edited CodeCogs in and added the code for the Newton method

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but it seems to me that you are encountering this error because of the huge values that are evaluated in your iterative algorith. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050907/python-overflowerror-math-range-error where the exp functions is the culprit (for you it could be the same due to those complex cosines). Whenever I use `exp`, I try to check that the exponent is not too big (more than 709.78)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the problem is with `cmath.cos()`.  If you look at `x` when it fails, you see that it is

```
(8996.29520764-8256.38535552j)
```

Which is rather large.

---

**Aside:** You say you're not sure how to debug.  There are lots of ways, but one easy way is to surround the statement that fails with a `try...except` block and then examine the value of `x` when an exception is encountered - e.g.

```
def f(x):
    try:
        y = pow(x,4)*cm.cos(x) - 1
    except OverflowError:
        print x
    return y
```

---

Using tigonometric substitutions for the complex maths `cos` function doesn't help either:

```
j = cm.sqrt(-1)
cos_part = (cm.exp(j * x) + cm.exp(-1*j*x))/2
```

fails with a similar error, as does:

```
cos_part = math.cos(x.real) * math.cosh(x.imag) - j * math.sin(x.real) * math.sinh(x.imag)
```

The latter fails because the hyperbolic functions fail.  When you think about it - it is not very surprising that `exp(8000)` or so fails - that's a ***huge*** number.  The largest that a 32 bit `double` can hold is about `math.exp(709)`.

**How does x get so large?**

Your problem is that `grad(x)` is very small at some points in your function, causing `xk` to explode in value.  This hapens as `xk` tends towards `(0 + 0j)` - `grad` tends to something very large!

You can see this by inserting `print` statements in the loop where you update `xk`

I'm not sure off the top of my head of the maths around how you're going to be able to control this, but I don't think that simply altering the precision will help.  You might consider looking at the behaviour of the function around its roots.

Your other function (the simple quartic one) does not exhibit this problematic behaviour.